# Conditional format first non-blank cell in multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, vba

Hopefully this will stop the chain.

See the linked questions if you want more background, but I need to conditional format multiple rows (2,000+) from the FIRST (leftmost) non-blank cell + the next 11 columns after it. Not sure if it's needed for the conditional format formula, but I am able to get the start cell for each row, can kind of get the end cell (see below).

Cell address of the first populated cell in the row (*the data starts on row 2, the values begin in column C and end in column P):

```
{=(ADDRESS(2,COLUMN(INDEX(C2:P2,MATCH(1,IF(C2:P2<>0,IF(C2:P2<>"",1)),0)))))}
```

^ this gets me an absoluted text-version of the leftmost populated cell in each row. I have all these addresses in a helper column. I am then able to get the desired stopping-point for the format (12th cell to the right of the cell returned from above formula), but I have to manually enter the cell address derived from above formula:

```
=ADDRESS(2,COLUMN(OFFSET(N2,0,11,1,1)))
```

I can't nest the start cell formula inside this second formula or it breaks.

THANK YOU!

Desired result (ignore the different colors, they can be the same):

[image]

Comment: Why is the "rock" row not colored?

Comment: Sorry, this is just from a different question that is linked to this. But you are right, the Rock row would be highlighted as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a helper column C that finds the first non blank in the row (my data went from column D to  column AZ)

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((D2:AZ2<>0),0),0)
```

My conditional format rule applied to D2 to AZ4 was to highlight when the following was true:

```
==AND(COLUMN(D2)<($C2+11+COLUMN($D2)),COLUMN(D2)>=$C2+COLUMN($C2))
```

You can modify this to put the helper column where you wish, and to use named ranges.

(Had to add condition to not start coloring before the first instance!)

Comment: I keep getting an error when I try to input this formula, from Excel itself. It's a pop-up saying there's a problem with the formula.

Comment: Which formula?  The helper?  When doing the conditional formatting make sure you are in the top left cell you want to start formatting (in this case D2)

Comment: No, the helper works fine. The conditional format formula. I go into the New Formatting Rule window and add that formula to the "Format values where this formula is true:" area (adapting it to my spreadsheet) and it won't even let me enter it, it keeps asking if I made a mistake.

Comment: Nevermind, it works. I was entering two == (I code too, so I'm sure that's just habit). I reduced it to one and I made sure the helper column was next to the table and it works. THANK YOU SO MUCH! This solves a *GIANT* headache for me.

Comment: Check my reply on your other question re new business
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942323/sum-column-if-cells-are-outside-range-range-leftmost-value-in-row-next-11-c